# How would you run cleanup after throwing an exception in an API wrapper?

Tags: php

At the moment, I'm running curl_init() in the constructor and curl_close() in the destructor. If a method throws an exception, the destructor would never get called, so the cURL session would remain open. I believe the session would close anyway once the script is finished executing, so it's not terribly important in this case, but hypothetically, if I needed the object to clean itself up after throwing exceptions, what would be the best way to handle this? I considered passing the object in question to a custom exception class, but that seems like it might be overkill. Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: Custom exception classes are never overkill. They're in the true spirit of OOP.

Comment: Fair enough. So would the object pass self to the custom exception class when it throws an exception? I don't think I've seen this done in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better solution, but I added...

```
register_shutdown_function(array($this, 'cleanup'));
```

... to the constructor and replaced the destructor with a cleanup method, which always runs, whereas the destructor only runs if no exceptions are thrown.